# Porting a MacRuby app over from 0.3 Leopard to 0.6 Lion yields errors

Tags: ruby, xcode, macruby

I'm not sure why this is blowing up on me. These errors weren't present until I built on 0.6 / Lion, which is quite a ways off from 0.3, I know, but still it should work, unless something funky changed with xcode.
 I don't see why it's complaining about this line. Driving me nuts. Any help is appreciated. Error:

```
   /Users/matthew.sacks/dev/mrHost/mrhost/build/mrhost-axyfekrprsyhptctrrnpsyeqwgjv/Build/Products/Debug/mrhost.app/Contents/Resources/host.rb:83:in `set_host': wrong number of arguments (2 for 0) (ArgumentError)
        from /Users/matthew.sacks/dev/mrHost/mrhost/build/mrhost-axyfekrprsyhptctrrnpsyeqwgjv/Build/Products/Debug/mrhost.app/Contents/Resources/rb_main.rb:22:in `swap_env'
        from /Users/matthew.sacks/dev/mrHost/mrhost/build/mrhost-axyfekrprsyhptctrrnpsyeqwgjv/Build/Products/Debug/mrhost.app/Contents/Resources/rb_main.rb:69:in `<main>'
```

Code is at https://github.com/msacks/mrhost/blob/master/host.rb

Answer (score 0):

That error says,

> On line 82 of `host.rb` there is a call to a method named `set_host`. You are passing in two arguments during your call to the method, but the method is not written to take any arguments.
>
> The above call was made inside the call to `swap_env`, made on line 22 of `rb_main.rb`
>
> …and *that* call was made from line 69 of `main.rb`